# Can anyone identify a story where astronauts delay their return to earth for tax reasons?

Tags: story-identification

A friend told me that he once read a science fiction short story in which a group of astronauts return to earth after a long voyage, but the British members of the expedition opted to remain in orbit for a couple of extra weeks because of tax reasons to do with residency.  Can anyone identify the story that he might be referring to?

Comment: I'd failed to remember it was a trip to the moon though. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it's "[A Question of Residence](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?65144)" by Arthur C Clarke, collected in *The Other Side of the Sky* and *The Best of Arthur C Clarke: 1937-1971*.

> *"A Question of Residence" tells of how at the end of the mission one
> of the ships would have to stay behind to clean up their equipment
> while the others return and get the early glory, and how **the British
> team end up volunteering... in order to take advantage of a legal
> loophole so they can sell their stories tax-free.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Wikipedia: Venture to the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venture_to_the_Moon)</sup></sub>

Comment: Great, many thanks!